# How do I set or remove the Default Response Content Type Using SwashBuckle

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swashbuckle

The default response content type when using SwashBuckle is `text/plain`. How can I change the default to be `application/json` or even remove `text/plain`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The response content of an end point is not determined by `Swashbuckle` but by the formatters set in the configuration of your ASP.NET Web API project.

To remove the `text/plain` content type and only support `application/json` you could add this to the `Register` method of your `WebApiConfig`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();

var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
jsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
jsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(jsonFormatter);
```

Comment: jsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); worked for me

Comment: Seems some syntax error there: C# doesn't allow more than one char inside `'` delimiters

Answer (score 4):

For ASP.NET Core 3 Web API, I had to do the following within the `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method:

```
services.AddControllers(options => options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<StringOutputFormatter>());
```

And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-5.0#special-case-formatters) you can find the corresponding documentation.

Comment: This removed only text/plain, but I still see text/json.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET Core 3 Web API and up, to restrict the response formats, you can apply the `[Produces]` filter. Like most Filters, `[Produces]` can be applied at the action, controller, or global scope. You can apply the filter to base controller that all your controller inherit from. Below filter will apply on all actions under SampleController. All endpoints under this controller will have `application/json` content type only:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class SampleController : ControllerBase
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: By the way  "Consumes" filter will limit accept Content Type header value => https://stackoverflow.com/a/75330117/6362361