# How to configure ASP.NET Core Web API to only accept `application/json`?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, http-accept-header

I would like to configure my ASP.NET Core Web API using .NET 6 to only accept `application/json` as the accept header value.
How can I configure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while, but adding the consumes attribute (rather than produces) will do the trick for you.

`[Consumes("application/json")]`

Answer (score 2):

Set `[Produces("application/json")]` for controller which can achieve the effect you want.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

[image]

For more details, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#content-negotiation).

Comment: The Op asked for content type of the request, not the response.